# How can I smooth my density curve so it has fewer peaks?

Tags: r, graph, plot

How can I limit the number of "humps" I allow in my density curve. I just want a nice looking skewed bell curve type thing. But right now, my density almost just looks like a line graph of my data.

Comment: Reproducible example, anyone?   And consider changing the smoothing parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the help for `density`.  There are a variety of parameters you can try changing, like the bw argument.